# Func delegate passed over a function

Tags: c#-4.0, delegates

I have the following code:

```
private void Example(Func<string,int> myDelegate)
{
    int length = myDelegate(RECEIVEDSTRING).; //How to access received string??
}
```

When I execute the method : Example(x=>"Hello".Length); How can I access to the string "Hello" inside the method Example?

Thanks.

Regards.

Jose.

Comment: Can you add some information why you'd want to do this? You could probably do something like this in a *very* complicated way using expression trees, but maybe there is a simpler solution to your problem.

Comment: Basically I'm interested in how linq extension methods works. I would like to understand where is the parameter value when a method is called from a client and the client pass a lambda expression. Thx.

Comment: Hi Leo, what I would like to do its a Linq Extension method but first I was trying to understand Func delegates. Reviewing my question again I think I have the solution. Basically I see that all Linq extensions that involves IEnumerable<T> has already the list instance into the method cause its an extension. Thx for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you should be processing this delegate. It takes an input parameter and `Example` needs to know some details about the input parameter in order to execute the delegate. Here `Example` "acts" as an interface to external code and that external code MUST provide their own implementation.
If `Example` needs to execute the delegate then it needs to provide the REQUIRED string parameter. IMHO, `Example` needs to provide a second parameter in its signature as below...

```
private void Example(string s, Func<string,int> myDelegate)
{
    int length = myDelegate(s);
}
```

Then external code can provide is own implementation and parameter...

```
Example("Hello", x => { return x.Length; });
```

What you are trying to do is not possible in `C#`, the delegate needs to an explicit context to run, that context is the string input parameter.

Hope it makes sense